# Assign static method to DependencyProperty of delegate type in xaml

Tags: c#, wpf

I have dependency property of delegate type in my class `MyEditBox`:

```
public delegate int LengthFilterDelegate(string text, int length);

public static readonly DependencyProperty LengthFilterProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register("LengthFilter", typeof(LengthFilterDelegate), typeof(MyEditBox), 
    new PropertyMetadata(new LengthFilterDelegate(lengthFilter)));

public LengthFilterDelegate LengthFilter
{
    get { return ((LengthFilterDelegate)(GetValue(LengthFilterProperty))); }
    set { SetValue(LengthFilterProperty, value); }
}

private static int lengthFilter(string text, int length)
{
    return 10;
}
```

and I want to assign static method of another class as value for it using style setter:

```
<Style TargetType="myns:MyEditBox">
    <Setter Property="LengthFilter" Value="{x:Static myns:TextWidthAutocadResolver.Resolve}"/>
</Style>
```

where `TextWidthAutocadResolver` class such as:

```
public static class TextWidthAutocadResolver
{
    public static int Resolve(string text, int length)
    {
        return 5;
    }
}
```

but for  some reason compiler cannot find `Resolve` method. What am doing wrong?

Comment: The `x:Static` markup extension can reference [a constant, a static property, a field, or an enumeration value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742135(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Yeah, it is the root of the problem, now I've added `public static Common.LimitedTextBox.LengthFilterDelegate ResolveDelegate = new Common.LimitedTextBox.LengthFilterDelegate(Resolve);` and used it in place of `Resolve` in xaml. You may write ur comment as answer.